# Debug Angular webpack project in Visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio-2015, webpack

I have created an ASP.NET MVC + Angular4 project in visual studio 2015. But I could not able to debug the typescript files both in chrome as well in Edge.

Can someone help me on this? using Webpack as module bundler.

Comment: https://augury.angular.io/ ?

Comment: thanks mate, I will give a try